# Convert from Ascii to hex, then sum result of the numbers

Tags: python

We have to write a function that takes a string and returns a number.

Every character of the string should be converted to the hex value of its ascii code first. The result should be the sum of the numbers in the hex strings (ignore letters).

We are struggling with converting ascii to hex..

This is what we have so far

```
def hex_hash(code):
# ascii to hex
# remove all the letters
# return the sum of the numbers 

#code.encode('hex')
#code.hex()

#code = hex(code)

code = code.fromascii(code).encode('hex')

sum = 0

for i in code:
    if i.isdigit():
        sum = sum + i 
return sum
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: "Yo" ==> "59 6f" ==> 5 + 9 + 6 = 20
"Hello, World!" ==> 48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21 ==> 91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(s):
    sm = 0
    for i in s:
        a = hex(ord(i))
        for j in a:
            if j.isdigit():
                sm += int(j)
    return sm
```

Sample input:

```
>>> func("Hello, World!")
91
```

**EDIT:** Explanation of the `hex(ord(i))` part

`ord(x)` gives the ASCII  value of that character, for example:

```
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> ord('0')
48
```

`hex(x)` returns hexadecimal string representation of an integer:

```
>>> hex(32)
'0x20'
>>> hex(100)
'0x64'
>>> hex(10)
'0xa'
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please ellaborate on the hex(ord(i)) part ?

Comment: but hex(ord()) is used to convert something to hex values right? why is hex() not enough?

Comment: `hex(n)` can only accept integers, thus `ord(ch)` has to be used to get the integer ASCII value of a character

Answer (score 1):

```
def hex_hash(s):
    h = ''.join(str(hex(ord(x))) for x in s)
    return sum(int(x) for x in h if x.isdigit())
```

sample usage:

```
>>> def hex_hash(s):
...     h = ''.join(str(hex(ord(x))) for x in s)
...     return sum(int(x) for x in h if x.isdigit())
... 
>>> 
>>> hex_hash('Yo')
20
>>> hex_hash("Hello, World!")
91
```

Comment: Thanks @bla ! I did not know you could write it in such an efficient way ;)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.